# Sintaxis de un arreglo equivocada PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, array

tengo un pequeño error de sintaxis con un arreglo de php (soy novato en php), sucede que necesito enviar a mi formulario la carga de 2 tablas diferentes a 2 select, ambos modelos me funcionan, ya probe cada uno y si los carga. Pero al enviar ambos dentro de un arreglo, no me funciona. Me marca error de sintaxis inesperado '=' esperando ')'. lo he intentado el arreglo de diferentes formas pero no me funciona. AYUDA POR FAVOR

```
public function registroC()
{
    $data['titulo'] = 'Registrar Ciudadano';

    $datos = array(
        ['localidades'] = $this->Registros_model->mostrarloc(),
        ['colonias'] = $this->Registros_model->mostrarcol());

    $this->load->view('plantillas/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('registro', $datos);
    $this->load->view('plantillas/footerlog');
}
```

Comment: Intenta usar esto: `$datos = array('localidades' => $this->Registros_model->mostrarloc()` y así para colonias a ver si se guarda el arreglo

Comment: solo cambia tu variable `$datos` por ` $datos = array('localidades' => $this->Registros_model->mostrarloc(),'colonias' => $this->Registros_model->mostrarcol());`

Comment: Esa forma que usas `array(['localidades']=$this->Registros_model->mostrarloc(), YLoDemás)` no la encontre en http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php prueba en luhar de usar **['localidades']=** sea **'localidades'=>** igual para el otro valor.

Comment: Gracias, me funciono de la manera en Roberto León Oramas me dijo. GRACIAS POR SUS COMENTARIOS Y POR SU AYUDA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Según la definición que quieres aplicar debería quedar de la siguiente manera

```
public function registroC()
{
    $data['titulo'] = 'Registrar Ciudadano';

    $datos = array(
      'localidades' => $this->Registros_model->mostrarloc(),
      'colonias'    => $this->Registros_model->mostrarcol()
    );

  $this->load->view('plantillas/header', $data);
  $this->load->view('registro', $datos);
  $this->load->view('plantillas/footerlog');
}
```

> De otra forma puedes aplicar la siguiente sintaxis

```
public function registroC()
{
  $data['titulo'] = 'Registrar Ciudadano';

  $datos['localidades'] = $this->Registros_model->mostrarloc();
  $datos['colonias']    = $this->Registros_model->mostrarcol();

  $this->load->view('plantillas/header', $data);
  $this->load->view('registro', $datos);
  $this->load->view('plantillas/footerlog');
}
```

> Las dos formas deberían causar el mismo efecto.
>
> Saludos.

Comment: Pues con la primera forma ya me funciono, gracias. Pero originalmente sin usar el array usaba la segunda forma casi igual (usaba $datos1 y $datos2 y en la vista usaba mandaba $this->load->view('registro', $datos1, $datos2); ), jajaja ya lo pobre de ambas formas y si funciona. Gracias

Comment: genial.Saludos.